# HTML / CSS - collapsible element that is filled automatically

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a bunch of text divs, which are generated using `ngRepeat`; they are too big.

Instead, I'd like to have in their place collapsibles. However, I'd like to see 2-3 sentences from the text above the button, and the rest collapsible.

```
<div>TEXT I WANT VISIBLE</div>

<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">TEXT I WANT COLLAPSED</div>
```

What's the best way to do this? The critical thing is that I don't want to manually select which text goes into the collapsible, and which doesn't - I'm looking for a way to automatically create this pair of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a CSS task than an AngularJS specific task. The idea is to set a class on each div generated through the `ng-repeat`, and toggle some other class that will show/hide that div independently using the `overflow` and `height` CSS properties.

For example, in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p class="container" ng-class="{'show': item.visible}">{{item.text}}</p>
  <button ng-click="item.visible = !item.visible">Show more</button>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.items = [
    {allShown: false, text: 'long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows'},
    {allShown: false, text: 'other long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows'},
    {allShown: false, text: 'another long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows long text that overflows'}
  ];
```

And the associated styles:

```
.container {
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.show {
   overflow: visible;
   height: auto;
}
```

Here is an example plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/23cMOs9gykp094A2sISD

Comment: Yes, this worked very well, thanks! One more question: what is a good way to set the `container height` value, other than a fixed `px` number? Can I make it dependent on something?

Comment: Can you give an example of what it would be dependent on? If it is truly dynamic you could use `ng-style`, or if there a few different fixed values it could take you can define some separate CSS classes and use `ng-class`.